# Common Lisp: Using (let) for evaluating recursive function

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, subset-sum

So I wrote something that returns a maximal subset sum given a list of positive integers. However, I would like to use the (let) so that I make the code more efficient. I would like to know if or how that is possible.

```
(defun subset-sum1 (numbers capacity)
  (subset-sum numbers capacity 0))

(defun subset-sum (numbers capacity counter) 
  (cond ((null numbers) counter)
        ((= counter capacity) counter) ;; return if counter 'hits' the capacity
        ((< capacity (+ (car numbers) counter))
         (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity counter)) ;; cdr if car branch exceeds capacity
        ((<= (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity counter)
             (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity (+ (car numbers) counter)))
         (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity (+ (car numbers) counter))) ;; choose car
        (t (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity counter)))) ;; choose cdr
```

The above code works fine in common lisp. But, I would like to do something like below, because I feel like using let will make the code better. But what I wrote goes into an infinite loop :( 
This is an assignment for an introductory AI class... help out a novice please!

```
(defun subset-sum (numbers capacity counter)
  (let ((exclude (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity counter))
   (include (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity (+ (car numbers) counter))))
     (cond ((null numbers) counter)
       ((= counter capacity) counter)
       ((< capacity (+ (car numbers) counter)) exclude)
       ((<= exclude include) include)
       (t (exclude)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an infinite loop because of these lines:

```
(defun subset-sum (numbers capacity counter)
  (let ((exclude (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity counter))
```

You keep calling **subset-sum** recursively, and it never terminates.  Even when you get to the end of the list, and **numbers** is **()**, you keep going, because **(cdr '())** is **'()**.  You handled this in the original by checking **(null numbers)** (though it might be more idiomatic to use **(endp numbers)**).  Now you can do something like:

```
(defun subset-sum (numbers capacity counter)
  (if (endp numbers)
    counter
    (let ((exclude (subset-sum (cdr numbers) capacity counter))
          ;...
         )
      (cond ; ...
          ))))
```

Comment: Okay it works now. So my understanding is that I want to put the basecase before using the conditional loop with let. Thanks a bunch!